# Disadvantages to using ext4 to store media on an (256GB) sd-card

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, sd-card

I like to keep my music (approx 140GB) and video (another 100GB) on an sd card. For one thing this makes moving to a new laptop easy.   Once the data is copied to the card, I'll mostly be mounting it read-only; occasionally remounting rw if I need to add files - alternatively, I could mount rw, but use the noatime option.

Is there any reason I shouldn't use ext4?

Presumably mounting read-only means that a journalling filesystem won't cause wear on the card (actually, since it's only reading, presumably the journal would be irrelevant)?

I have read various sources which suggest that using the existing exFAT filesystem could produce significant load on the OS, in case you're wondering why I don't just go with that.

Comment: *"Is there any reason I shouldn't use ext4?"* -- It is not as portable as a FAT filesystem would be.  *"I have read various sources which suggest that using the existing exFAT filesystem could produce significant load on the OS"* -- I'd be interested in reading about that.  Could you please post some links?    Otherwise I concur with your other assumptions (i.e. journaling).

Comment: I'll try to update with some sources re exFAT, and I should have mentioned that I don't care about portability.  It'll be on my Linux laptop.  I have no interest in running anything other than Linux on the machine.  Please nudge me I've I've not updated with those links in a day or two.

Comment: Since you only read, is irrelevant the journaling. I use for many years SD cards with btrfs for write / read. No problem.

You can disable journaling. https://superuser.com/questions/516784/disable-journaling-on-ext4-filesystem-partition